# Elasticsearch rename_pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, indices, elasticsearch-indices

I have indices i need to restore from snapshot, by using rename_pattern and rename_replacement. Can someone help me with the pattern and replacement?

Let's say my input index name is: "abc_def_r22_0"
and I want it restored as "abc_def_r44_0"

```
NUM="44"
 POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
{
 "indices": "abc_def_r22_0",
 "ignore_unavailable": "true",
 "include_global_state": false,
 "rename_pattern": "\\d\\d",
 "rename_replacement": "$1'$NUM'_0"
 }
```

Comment: I assume all indices follow the same pattern?

Comment: They all have the "r22".

`code`
abc_def_r22_0
abc_ghi_r22_0
abc_jkl_r22_1
`code`

I only want to update the "22" from an input variable.

Comment: Try `_r[0-9]+_` and replace with `_r$NUM_`

Comment: You're right. It worked. I used: `r(\\d+)` with `r$NUM`

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels

Comment: I'd suggest using @WiktorStribiżew's answer as it ensures there's a `_` surrounding it. It's more precise.

Comment: Also, the capturing group is not necessary since you are not using the capture in the replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
_r[0-9]+_
```

and replace with `_r$NUM_`.

The `_r[0-9]+_` will match `_r`, 1 or more digits, and a `_`, so you need to replace it with `_r`, then a new number and a `_`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mepQWv/1).